# JedisClientConfigurationBuilder - JedisClientConfiguration - how to turn on ssl and usepooling both in JedisConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

In spring JedisClientConfigurationBuilder interface , there are 2 methods,

```
        JedisSslClientConfigurationBuilder useSsl();

        JedisPoolingClientConfigurationBuilder usePooling();
```

I am able to either use one of them..

```
JedisClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().build()
Or
JedisClientConfiguration.builder().usePooling().build()
```

How to use both (ssl and pooling) at the same time using JedisClientConfiguration builder?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..

```js
JedisClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().and().usePooling().build())
```